# Is there enough overlap between these four "space ship shape" questions to close at least one as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close, exact-duplicates

Is there enough overlap between these four "space ship shape" questions to close at least one as duplicate?

- [Are there enough stray gasses in space to justify streamlining a probe?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1884/12102)
- [Is the streamlining of a launch vehicle worth the additional fuel required to carry it beyond the Karman line?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4612/12102)
- [Is streamline body shape essential for propagation in the vacuum of space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51061/12102)
- [What would be the most appropriate shape for a satellite going to mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51323/12102)

It seems like there might be...

Answer (score 1):

I think that this question should be closed: [Is streamline body shape essential for propagation in the vacuum of space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/51061/is-streamline-body-shape-essential-for-propagation-in-the-vacuum-of-space)

As it seems to be a duplicate of this: [Are there enough stray gasses in space to justify streamlining a probe?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1884/are-there-enough-stray-gasses-in-space-to-justify-streamlining-a-probe)